# symget - a list of macro variables

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm trying to reproduce the code found here, specifically on page 7:
http://www.nesug.org/proceedings/nesug04/pm/pm13.pdf

```
/* set up example*/
%let var_1 = 'abc';
%let var_2 = 'def';
%let var_3 = 'ghi';
%let val_1 = 1.5;
%let val_2 = 3;
%let val_3 = 4.5;

/* use symget to create a list of var names and values */
data scores;
  length var_name $32 value 8.;

  do _N_ = 1 to 3;
    var_name = symget('var_' || left(_N_));
    value    = symget('val_' || left(_N_));
  end;
run;
```

However, the end result that I'm getting is only the last variable, not all 3:

```
var_name    value
ghi         4.5
```

I want:

```
var_name    value
abc         1.5
def         3
ghi         4.5
```

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing an `output` statement to write each row.  Insert it here:

```
do _N_ = 1 to 3;
  var_name = symget('var_' || left(_N_));
  value    = symget('val_' || left(_N_));
  output;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks--figured it had to be something simple.